# Negation in cmd and powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

Is there a way to do negation in cmd or powershell? In other words, what I want is to find all files that do not meet a certain criteria (other than attribute where negation is specified as "-") say in the name. It would be helpful if there was a generic negation that could be used in other contexts as well. In addition, for powershell, is there a way to get the list of file names and then store it as an array that can be sorted etc?

Apologies for asking something that seems so basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With PowerShell there are many ways to negate a set of criteria, but the best way depends on the situation. Using a single negation method in every situation could be very inefficient at times. If you wanted to return all items that were not DLLs older than 05/01/2011, you could run:

```
#This will collect the files/directories to negate
$NotWanted = Get-ChildItem *.dll| Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt '05/01/2011'}
#This will negate the collection of items
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$NotWanted -notcontains $_}
```

This could be very inefficient since every item passing through the pipeline will be compared to another set of items. A more efficient way to get the same result would be to do:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
  Where-Object {($_.Name -notlike *.dll) -or ($_.CreationTime -ge '05/01/2011')}
```

As @riknik said, check out:

```
get-help about_operators
get-help about_comparison_operators
```

Also, many cmdlets have an "Exclude" parameter.

```
# This returns items that do not begin with "old"
Get-ChildItem -Exclude Old*
```

To store the results in an array that you can sort, filter, reuse, etc.:

```
# Wrapping the command in "@()" ensures that an array is returned
# in the event that only one item is returned.
$NotOld = @(Get-ChildItem -Exclude Old*)

# Sort by name
$NotOld| Sort-Object
# Sort by LastWriteTime
$NotOld| Sort-Object LastWriteTime

# Index into the array
$NotOld[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I completely understand what you're looking for. Maybe something like this (in PowerShell)?

```
get-childitem | where-object { $_.name -notlike "test*" }
```

This gets all the files in the current directory, where their names don't start with the phrase test.

To get more info on operators, use PowerShell's built-in help:

```
get-help about_operators
get-help about_comparison_operators
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @riknik mentioned, for the specific case of Get-ChildItem and file name, you should use the `-exclude` which will be more efficient.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\scripts\*.* -exclude *.txt,*.log
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx